# Sending messages to MSMQ private queue using HTTP, without AD

Tags: c#, msmq

I have computers A and B on two different networks.
Both computers have MSMQ installed.
Computer A has some code in C# that sends a message to a private queue in computer B.
It doesn't throw any errors, but the message doesn't get delivered.

The output queue of computer A has a queue created by the path name I gave and it contains the message I was trying to send.

Please see the code below. Any help is much appreciated.

```
MessageQueue messageQueue = new MessageQueue();
messageQueue.Path="FormatName:DIRECT=HTTP://[IP Address of Computer B]/msmq/Private$/vouchers1";
messageQueue.Send(voucher, "test");
```

Comment: What's the status of the outgoing queue?

Comment: I've written 17 different blogs posts on "MSMQ messages using HTTP just won’t get delivered". Pretty sure one will cover your problem.  https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/johnbreakwell/tag/msmq-over-http/